# How can I get access to the current access token in controller's action?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core 2.1 web API app with IdentityServer4. I use `client_credentials` flow for clients to access the API.

In a controller's action (on server side), I would get access to current `client_id`. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2):

Add the necessary using statement:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
```

Then get the token within the action method:

```
var accessToken = await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.GetTokenAsync(
    HttpContext, OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
```

Comment: I’ve also figured out, that I can get all information in the context of controller by accessing `User.Claims` and filtering by `JwtClaimsType`